# replace h2 with h1 in an Elementor Pro "archive products" widget

Tags: woocommerce, elementor, code-snippets

I would like to change all the product titles on this page (https://alessandramilano.eu/all-shoes/) from H2 to H1. How can I do?

I have tried different codes but I can't get to the solution. Do I have to insert a CSS code or do I have to modify the "Elementor" theme code?

Comment: Is that your website? Or you are trying to edit the elements on the website. If it isnt yours, you can look into selenium for automation or editing a page.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the product widget, on the right hand side you'll have the ability to change all the headings in the Layout tab. In your case they can all be changed from H1 to H2.

It's not necessary to modify any html or css.